# GUI SVN client for Debian Linux

Tags: linux, svn, debian, svn-client

Does any one know of a good, free, GUI SVN client for Linux?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> [KDESVN](https://github.com/KDE/kdesvn) A feature-rich client with great history and revision views, annotated code views showing who changed each line of code and when it was changed, and 3D graphical views of branching and merging among trees. Written in C++ with Qt, but using KDE libraries (which are somewhat troublesome to get on Windows).
>
> Unfortunately, the developer of KDESVN [stopped the development](http://kdesvn.alwins-world.de/blog/2012-04-02/stop) and is shutting down its track website in summer 2012 (EDIT: he [resumed development](http://kdesvn.alwins-world.de/blog/2012-06-22/restart) of maintenance releases in June 2012).
>
> [RabbitVCS](http://rabbitvcs.org/) A Python extension to integrate Subversion functionality into the Nautilus File Manager, basically as a clone of the TortoiseSVN project on Windows. —[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Subversion_clients)

Answer (score 7):

[RapidSVN](http://rapidsvn.tigris.org/) is a pretty decent multi-platform client.

Answer (score 5):

[SmartSVN](https://www.smartsvn.com/) is very useful. It is shareware, but after 30 days you still can use limited edition and it still remains effective.

Answer (score 3):

If you consider **vim** to be visual, then you can get the [vcscommand](http://code.google.com/p/vcscommand/) plugin.

[image]
<sub>(source: [vim.org](http://www.vim.org/images/vim_header.gif))</sub>

Answer (score 3):

Seen a bunch. Officially declare: command line is waaay more effective, and naturally integrates with other GNU utilities. Learn the command line! :) It's free, visual, and very good. And it's simpler than it seems.

Answer (score 2):

I've used [Subcommander](http://subcommander.tigris.org/), which worked quite well, although nowadays I usually use [Subclipse](http://subclipse.tigris.org/) from within Eclipse along with the command-line.

Answer (score 2):

And then there's Emacs ;-)  Has a number of "visual" clients, or rather, a number of solutions for integrating SVN (and git, hg, bzr, cvs even...).

Answer (score 1):

SVN Workbench is a nice multi-platform tool you should consider. It's written in Python and here's the official homepage: http://pysvn.tigris.org/docs/WorkBench.html

It's available for Linux, Mac and Windows and it's also present in the Ubuntu official repository.

Answer (score 0):

After following through the list of items, I was disappointed with the quality of the solutions available on Linux.

I discovered through more digging on the net that konquorer had built in some very nice subversion integrations several years ago and I'm quite impressed with the quality.

Note that konqueror requires [kde, kdesvn and kompare](http://svn.haxx.se/users/archive-2006-11/1215.shtml).

The solution still no where near TortoiseSVN for windows but its still very useful for many usecases and a relief for us Windows to *nix desktop converts.

My current distribution is OpenSuse 13 with KDE.